# Verificar nome do módulo via VBA

Tags: vba

Olá, preciso verificar o nome de um módulo para altera-lo em posterior.

O nome do módulo se altera bastante, dependendo de cada documento,e não da pra rodar todos os nomes possíveis, pois demoraria muito.

Pra isso preciso de um código que leia os nomes dos módulos no meu projeto VBA.

O que realizei até então foi isso:

```
Sub Mudar_cód()

    ObjVbProj = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).VBProject.VBComponents("MFPC0000").CodeModule

    If ObjVbProj = "MFPC0000" Then

        MsgBox "SIM"

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se a função abaixo te ajuda, pois lista todas os módulos por planilha:

```
Sub BuscaModulos()
Dim modName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim l As Long

 Set wb = ThisWorkbook

For l = 1 To wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Count
    With wb.VBProject.VBComponents(l)
        modName = modName & vbCr & .Name
    End With
Next

 MsgBox "Resultado:" & vbCr & modName
 Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfeito! Eu só vou encaixar no código no meu código, mas era exatamente isso.